# SAP HANA : Most performant way to insert / import data into tables from CSV files

Tags: import, insert, database-performance, hana

We want to give a user the possibility to upload and insert / import data into tables. The data from users is in CSV files.

So fare we thought of three possibilities:

- Direkt import via XSJS Application -> (Batch) Insert each row
- Import via `IMPORT FROM` statement
- SDI (Replication)

At the moment we favor direct import (XSJS inserts) since the user is able to open a file-choose dialog and select a file. (Simplicity)

Unfortunately the inserts are very slow (20 min / 1 Mio rows).
Batch insert reduces to about 5 min
Parallel calling the Batch-Import XSJS with packages of 100k reduces to about 1 min.

However CSV import command `IMPORT FROM` with 4 Threads is much faster than 1 minute (about 15 sec)

**So the questions is how to import data into HANA in a fast way (Preferably with XSJS technologie)**

**System Environment**

We built a web user interface with-in the XS Engine for doing various data intensive tasks.

A new task is to load data into SAP HANA for further processing.

The data is in CSV files from partner companies

Answer (score 2):

Feeding in data via XSJS is an approach that requires the data to pass many system boundaries. Using a JDBC/ODBC based data loading tool is usually the better way here.

`IMPORT` and `IMPORT FROM` are both **server-side** commands that require access to a filesystem share that can be accessed by the SAP HANA nodes too.

They are primarily meant for "technical" data loading, e.g. making system copies and developer/admin data movement.
The end user is not an intended audience.

Given that you mentioned that your end users should be able to load the data, providing them with such a data loading tool (maybe even writing a simple one yourself) could be an option here.

Alternatively, using SDI could be a viable option, if the structure of the data doesn't change often.

Comment: Thanks you Lars for pointing out the intention of the import command.

Comment: Unfortunately we are only able to use XSJS since we did not migrate to XSA - yet (Else we would use Java). But it also looks like the batch insert is the slow part - not the transfer from the client to HANA.

Comment: Further explained the use case in the question

Comment: @Thorsten do you think it will be possibile for you to share the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SuShuang sure view the answer - hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

We did some test with Java which was fast (java with multi-threading is twice as fast as XSJS).

Since the Customer want's a web-gui and Java Webstart is deprecated and has some more issues we use now the web solution:

1. `var conn = $.hdb.getConnection();`
2. `conn.executeUpdate('INSERT INTO ' + schemaName + '.' + targetTableName + ' VALUES(' + placeholder + ')', argsArray);`

**It is important to**

- use the newer `$.hdb` connection not the `$.db` connection (many tutorials use the `$.db` connection.
- use batch insert